# UISlider unwanted behaviour while animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

I am using a UISlider in my app where I add max and min image for slider. Every thing works good but look at the image below. When I click on button the animation starts and values on label change but the animation on slider directly jumps to 6 which you can see it and the same thing happens when the slider reaches it max value(100) from 96 the slider min image(orange color) disappears and the label continues to show values 97..98..99..100.[image]

Here's the code snippet for reference :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIImage *sliderMinimum = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_max"]    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14 topCapHeight:0];
  [self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:sliderMinimum forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  UIImage *sliderMaximum = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_min"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14 topCapHeight:0];
  [self.slider setMaximumTrackImage:sliderMaximum forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
[self.slider setValue:0 animated:true];
[self setSliderValue:2];
}

- (void)setSliderValue:(float)value
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [self.slider setValue:value animated:true];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.lblSliderValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.slider.value];
    if (self.slider.value != self.slider.maximumValue) {
        [self setSliderValue:value+1];
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: You need to force a refresh of the UI component...  setNeedsDisplay

Comment: @Dominic how do i set it and where ! Can you elaborate your solution plz

Comment: put this after you set the text...   [self.lblSliderValue setNeedsDisplay]

Comment: I would also recommend wrapping your [self setSliderValue:value+1]; line inside:  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ your code goes here }); to delay the next animation until the after the current run loop has completed.

Comment: @Dominic let me clear! The label is showing perfect values as animation starts i.e. 1-100 my prob is the  slider animation that directly jumps to 6. You can see the gif image in my question

Comment: [self.slider setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: There is no UISlider in your code or your screen shot. What does this question have to do with UISlider? If that thing _is_ a UISlider, then you are making a big mistake in saying `[self.slider setValue:value animated:true]`, because `animated:true` has not worked correctly in years.

Comment: @matt The animating part is my UISlider , I have removed the slider thumb image. And if it's not working from years then it's absolutely fine. But it's strange that no one produced a proper solution for this. Thanx  a lot Matt for informing me about it or else i would have wasted more time in searching a proper solution.

Comment: But that's not the point. The point is that the thing you are animating looks like a UIProgressView and acts like a UIProgressView. So why don't you _use_ a UIProgressView? After all, that's what you are trying to do - you want to let the user _view progress_.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
[slider addTarget:self
  action:@selector(roundValue:) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And in the roundValue function set the value:

```
- (void)roundValue{

    [slider setValue:((int)((slider.value + 0) / 1) * 1) animated:NO];

   }
```

Comment: No Success mate! if animation is set to NO it moves faster. But if Its set Yes/true it skips first 5 values and last 5 values

Comment: You set minimum and maximum value..thats right.... please also set the     slider.value = 0; ... may be after setting this value..it start from 0

Comment: i have set the value to 0. And it does start from 0 no doubt. The animation part is skipping the bar 0-5 and directly jumps to 6 and continues smoothly till 95 and again same for remaining 5 values